# How to make responsive video embedding set in row with another div and both share same height?

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am trying to align a tow divisions in the same row and force both of them to share the same height.

[image: video responsive embidding and material card division]

On the  left is a material card div and the on the right there is a responsive video embedding.

in order to make the video embedding responsive I've used the following style to it:

```
.embed-container {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .embed-container iframe,
    .embed-container object,
    .embed-container embed {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Which makes video div hidden when including it inside a flex box

I've tried to:

1. Include them in a flex row
2. Used table row/cell CSS

[**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twavfk)

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular Material Sidenav component

> The sidenav components are designed to add side content to a
>   fullscreen app. To set up a sidenav we use three components:
>    which acts as a structural container for our
>   content and sidenav,  which represents the main
>   content, and  which represents the added side content.

[**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twavfk-wpqh7b)